# set paper size in print page template in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing, print-preview

how to **set paper size in print template** in **internet explorer** with **java script** 
When you use a custom template for printing and previewing with Internet Explorer

```
//printer.pageWidth and printer.pageHeight are read only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MeadCo's ScriptX](http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx/docs/printdoc.asp#paperSize) :

> MeadCo's ScriptX is a suite of ActiveX technology components designed
>   to provide absolute control over document printing operations from
>   client and server computers running the Microsoft Windows Web Browsing
>   Platform.